# Index main songtitle and subtitle separately

Tags: songs

My songbook has two titles, English and Khmer in `beginsong{}`. 
When I call `showindex`, both titles appear on one same index.

### My purpose is to have two index separately on its own page, one index for English title, one index for Khmer title (subtitle?). How can we do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[Khmer,Latin]{ucharclasses} 
\usepackage{songs} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\newfontfamily\khos[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=0.85,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS}

\newfontfamily\adobegp{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\khos}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\rmfamily}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\sepindexesfalse
\newindex{idxtitleone}{idxtitleone}
%====================
\begin{document}
%====================
\begin{songs}{idxtitleone}

\beginsong{Doxology \\ សរសើរតំកើង}
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav’n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse{}
\endsong

\beginsong{Amzing Grace \\ ព្រះគុណអស្ចារ្យ}
\beginverse
Amzing grace, how sweet the sound
\endverse \endsong

\end{songs}
\onecolumn
\showindex[2]{Index by Titles}{idxtitleone}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  to properly display a block of code, highlight it with your mouse, then click on the `{}` icon above the input box.  for short bits of code, wrap them in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
Kevin helped me with magic.

- remove default index at `beginsong`.
- using both `\indextitleentry{khtitleidx}` and `\indextitleentry{entitleidx}` instead

Thanks Kevin!